# Locking down read/write access for a specific node based on user

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-security, emberfire

I know there have been similar issues to mine, but I'm still a bit stumped on how to secure my Firebase properly.

First, I'm using EmberFire. Second, I'm using Firebase Email/Password authentication for account management. Each of my accounts represents a business. I'd like it so that the currently authenticated business can only access his/her data. Initially, my thinking was to use the following data structure:

```
+ businesses
    - uid-1
    - uid-2
    - uid-3
```

...where uid is what's assigned to the user by Firebase email/password authentication. I would then use the following security rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "businesses": {
      "$user_id": {
        ".read": "$user_id === auth.uid",
        ".write": "$user_id === auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

With all that said, two questions:

1. Will it work? (Pretty sure it will based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21500946/firebase-how-to-list-user-specific-data))
2. If so, how can I get EmberFire to allow me to use my own id rather than what's generated by `push()`, which is used by EmberFire under the hood according to the docs.

**UPDATE**
With regards to EmberFire, here's the code I'm using to save my model to Firebase:

```
var business = _this.store.createRecord('business', {
    uid: userData.uid,
    businessName: _this.get('businessName'),
    firstName: _this.get('firstName'),
    lastName: _this.get('lastName')
});

business.save().then(function(success) {
    flashMessages.success('Your account has been created! Please login below.');
    _this.transitionToRoute('login');
}, function(error) {
    flashMessages.warning(error);
});
```

What I'm seeing is that the root node of these created objects ends up being a unique timestamp ID generated by Firebase. To solve my issue, I'd like to override that to the auth.uid.

Thanks in advance!
James

Comment: Thanks, Frank. I updated my original post to show the EmberFire-related code I'm using to save to Firebase. As noted, the root notes of those objects end up being Firebase IDs generated by `push()` under the hood, so the question is: can I override it so I can use auth.uid as the root node for what I save?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen, the solution below worked to fix my EmberFire issue, but I still cant get the permissioning to work properly using the schema above. Here's a JS bin that illustrates what I'm trying to do: http://jsbin.com/woyaculata/1/edit?html,js,console,output . Again, appreciate all the help.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen the questions were related. I wasn't going to worry about needing to override the key in EmberFire if the proposed security rules I mentioned above wouldn't have worked. And FYI, in response to your first reply, I did try the rules initially, but ran into problems, which is why I posted in the first place. That said, if you don't want to help, that's fine -- just don't reply. It would have been better than your snippy response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify `id` when doing the `createRecord`. The `id` will become the firebase **key**:

```
var record = this.store.createRecord('business', {
  id: userData.uid,
  businessName: this.get('businessName'),
  firstName: this.get('firstName'),
  lastName: this.get('lastName')
});
```

You will probably want to make sure that the user record doesn't already exist before creating it, so you'll need a "find or create" flow. There are some gotchas when doing this kind of flow in Ember Data. An example workaround is outlined in the comments [here](https://github.com/firebase/emberfire/issues/146#issuecomment-89444041)

Comment: Welp, that was almost too simple. Thank you very much! I'll def check out the workaround. Again, really appreciate your help!

Comment: Follow up: while the `id` fix you mentioned above worked for the EmberFire issue, I am getting `permission_denied` errors when trying to write to `businesses/$user_id` as outlined using the security rules mentioned above. Any suggestions? Thanks!